# Printing a Binary search Tree in a certain format diagram. in c

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to print a Binary search tree and it should look like a tree means if I have a tree which is 5,6,7 the printing function will print it like [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZPiC.png):

```
insert
5
insert
6
insert
7
Tree is:
    5
        6
            7
```

Now lets say a tree is 4,3,7 the result should be like
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVByI.png):

```
insert
4
insert
3
insert
7
tree is:
    4
3       7
```

There is 1 restriction: it should be done recursively.

This is the code I tried to solve this problem with:

```
void PrintTabs(int n)
{
  if(n==0)
  {
      return;
  }
  else
  {
      printf("\t");
      PrintTabs(--n);
  }
}

void PrintTree(BST* root, int level)
{
     if (root==NULL)
     {
         return;
     }
     PrintTree(root->Right,++level);
     PrintTabs(level);
     printf("%d\n",*(int*)root->Value);
     PrintTree(root->Left,++level);
}
```

My 2 main issues are it always printed sliding right, so I moved the printing section between the two recursive calls it had given me a bad result but somehow it had a format of the tree I looked for

Comment: I think the idea of being a student is you do the exercise yourself. You should  at least attempt to solve the problem first.

Comment: I tried myself a few times , but I can not backtrack the original root , I mean I print the leafs before the roots plus I can not form it right , believe me I tried for hours on hours , my last choice was to ask this question here.

Comment: OK - good that you are having a go at it and that you have narrowed down the actual issue that you are having. That helps people solve your problem quickly. I suggest you edit the question and post the bit of your code that recurses and maybe people can see where you are going wrong. However, of the top off my head, the original root will be available once you return to the back of the call stack.

Comment: post your code in order to further about it

Comment: Thank you for the quick response , I am new to StackOverFlow. soon i will post the function I tried to write.

Comment: @Daniel Hermon, see my answer below. You need to change the alignment based on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// This is used to find the leftmost node from the root (i.e, how much left). This is computed so that root is printed in the center.

```
findAlignment (BST * root, int *leftMost, int leftness) {

    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (leftness > *leftMost) {
        *leftMost = leftness;
    }

    findAlignment (root->left, leftMost, (leftness + 1));
    findAlignment (root->right, leftMost, (leftness - 1));

}
```

// This prints the tree using the leftmost node info. It adjusts the cursor position based on level and the leftness of the node to directly print.

```
void PrintTree(BST* root, int leftAlignment, int level)
{
     if (root==NULL)
     {
         return;
     }

     // the first printf aligns the position of cursor on the screen.
     // This code may not be portable on all machines.
     // see http://c-faq.com/osdep/termcap.html for details.
     // This particular print moves the cursor to row: 'level' and col: 'leftAlignment * 4'. 
     // You can change the multiplication factor from 4 based on
     // how many chars root->value will have and your other requirements to make it properly align.
     // You can also multiply level by some factor, if you want to align better.
     printf("\033[%d;%dH", level, leftAlignment * 4);
     printf("%d",root->Value);

     PrintTree(root->Left, leftAlignment - 1, level + 1);
     PrintTree(root->Right, leftAlignment + 1, level + 1);
}

int leftMost = 0;
findAlignment (root, &leftMost, 0);
printf("\033[2J"); // clear screen
printTree (root, leftMost, 0);
```

Comment: I have not taken care for overlapping cases (overlapping because alignment not adjusted properly). That may need some more work in the findAlignment function or need to add some more logic. But, this above code should work for most simple binary search trees.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I don't have enough rep. to post this as a comment. Since BST's are usually meant to only recurs one way (down), I would go about this a little differently. What if for each node, you figure out if it went left or right, and just keep track of that position in the node. Ex. I went left twice and right once, so my difference from root is -1 (to the left once). Each time you add a node, you can copy the parent's position and just add 1 or -1 for the child. Then you can easily use that number with your tabs function to step through the tree and add tabs as needed.

```
                          root(0)
                     left(-1)       right(1)
                 left(-2)  right(0)
```