# Printing a 2d binary search tree in c

Tags: c, recursion, printing, tree, binary-search-tree

I have to make a binary search tree (recursively) in c. Part of what i have to do is print the tree in it's 2 dimensional form.

[image: 01]

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C How to "draw" a Binary Tree to the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801740/c-how-to-draw-a-binary-tree-to-the-console)

Comment: answered last week here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725239/printing-a-binary-search-tree-in-a-certain-format-diagram-in-c/34730569#34730569

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code.